# Libgdx translation weird

Tags: java, libgdx

In a game I'm writing I need a huge world. So I divided it in chunks of 12x12 blocks (1 unit).

To render a chunk I want to use local coordinates: for every chunk I want 0;0 to be at the bottom left corner of the chunk.

[image]

In green world coord system where 1;1 is 1 block, same for chunk, only the origin is changing.

So to do this I use a transform matrix in my SpriteBatch which have a translation of chunk_x * chunk size and chunk_y * chunk size. But it acts weird for chunk y=-1.

Here's the world render code:

```
public void render() {
    batch.setProjectionMatrix(camera.combined);
    renderer.setProjectionMatrix(camera.combined);
    Matrix4 matrix4 = new Matrix4();
    for(Chunk chunk : Collections.unmodifiableCollection(loadedChunks.values())) {
        matrix4.setToTranslation(chunk.getX() * Chunk.SIZE, chunk.getY() * Chunk.SIZE, 0);
        batch.setTransformMatrix(matrix4);
        renderer.setTransformMatrix(matrix4);
        chunk.render(batch, renderer);
    }
}
```

I update the camera in a separate method. Here's the chunk render code:

```
public void render(SpriteBatch batch, ShapeRenderer renderer) {
    batch.begin();
    for(EntityBlock block : blockLayer0) {
        block.render(batch);
    }
    for(EntityBlock block : blockLayer1) {
        block.render(batch);
    }
    batch.end();
    renderer.begin(ShapeRenderer.ShapeType.Line);
        renderer.setColor(Color.WHITE);
        renderer.rect(0, 0, SIZE /* SIZE is constants and = 12 */, SIZE);
    renderer.end();
}
```

Render method in my entity block :

```
 @Override
public void render(SpriteBatch batch) {
    batch.draw(texture, get(PositionComponent.class).getX(), get(PositionComponent.class).getY(), 1f, 1f);
}
```

Here is a test map of 4 chunks from (-1;0) to (0;1) but I got the same result :

[image]

To give more details about entity's getComponent() method, my entity class extends ComponentProvider that have a map, Component> and i add to it a PositionComponent that store 2 floats x and y. So i didnt post the code because it works

PS : At the right of the black part is x = 0.

Comment: Where do you call `batch.begin()` and `batch.end()`? I don't really see what's causing your issue. It's probably in how you set up your EntityBlock arrays, which you didn't show. And by the way, is the white grid just for debugging? Because it's breaking up your batching.

Comment: Yeah sry i missed to add some code and the grid is for debugging, i'll update later

Comment: I would simplify the code to do exactly what you think you are doing now in only four manual steps for chunks (0,0),(-1,0),(0,-1),(-1,-1) and see if the problem persists. We also can't see what get(PositionComponent.class).getX() is doing, and that seems to be integral.

Comment: So I did what you said for a little map and it persists (i updated post). And for get(PositionComponent.class) it just store entity's position i could do a entity.getX() or similar if you prefer but problem does not come by this way. I don't know why negative translation i acting like this

Answer (score 0):

So after some experiments, i went to this conclusion : negative translation is not working as I want, and chunks are shifted of a too much amount (only with the spritebatch, shaperenderer working normally). So I wrote the misplacement, and with this code it is working (in World.render()) :

```
public void render() {
    Matrix4 matrix4 = new Matrix4();
    for(Chunk chunk : loadedChunks) {
        matrix4.setToTranslation((chunk.getX() * Chunk.SIZE) < 0 ? chunk.getX() * Chunk.SIZE + Chunk.SIZE - 1 : chunk.getX() * Chunk.SIZE, chunk.getY() * Chunk.SIZE, 0);
        batch.setTransformMatrix(matrix4);
        matrix4.setToTranslation(chunk.getX() * Chunk.SIZE, chunk.getY() * Chunk.SIZE, 0);
        renderer.setTransformMatrix(matrix4);
        chunk.render(batch, renderer);
    }
}
```

It's a temporary solution, but it works.